# Asp.net 3.5 localization, can't get it working

Tags: asp.net, localization

This is really simple, can't understand why I can't get it working. In asp.net 3.5 I'm trying to use localization and French using Global Resources. But it never uses the French resource file.

I have three files: Default.aspx, Resource.resx, Resource.fr.resx.

In Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Culture="fr-FR" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Label ID="lblWelcomeMsg" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, welcomeMessage %>"></asp:Label>
```

In App_GlobalResources/Resource.resx:

```
Name: welcomeMessage
Value: Welcome
```

In App_GlobalResources/Resource.fr.resx (have also tried using Resource.fr-FR.resx):

```
Name: welcomeMessage
Value: Bonjour
```

The problem is that it always says "Welcome" even if I set the culture to "fr-FR". I have also tried to set the language in the browser but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set the culture in web.config for example (for auto):

```
<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto"/>
```